# How can I download a python package with dependencies for a specific python version of an offline cross-platform?

Tags: python, download, pip, cross-platform

I have an online Windows PC with Python 3.10.10 and pip 23.0.1. I want to download a python package and its dependencies for an offline computer that has a 64-bit Linux and Python 3.6.8. I tried:

```
pip download --platform=linux_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --python-version=3.6.8 podman-compose
```

**Actual result**:

```
Collecting podman-compose
  Using cached podman_compose-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting python-dotenv
  Using cached python_dotenv-0.20.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting podman-compose
  Using cached podman_compose-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
  Using cached podman_compose-0.1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached podman_compose-0.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached podman_compose-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
  Using cached podman_compose-0.1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
  Using cached podman_compose-0.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Using cached podman_compose-0.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Using cached podman_compose-0.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install podman-compose==0.1.10, podman-compose==0.1.11, podman-compose==0.1.3, podman-compose==0.1.4, podman-compose==0.1.5, podman-compose==0.1.8, podman-compose==0.1.9, podman-compose==1.0.2 and podman-compose==1.0.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    podman-compose 1.0.3 depends on pyyaml
    podman-compose 1.0.2 depends on pyyaml
    podman-compose 0.1.11 depends on pyyaml
    podman-compose 0.1.10 depends on pyyaml
    podman-compose 0.1.9 depends on pyyaml
    podman-compose 0.1.8 depends on pyyaml
    podman-compose 0.1.5 depends on pyyaml
    podman-compose 0.1.4 depends on pyyaml
    podman-compose 0.1.3 depends on pyyaml

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

I do not fully understand, what is happening here, but it looks like it tries to get all possible package versions and fails because they all require different dependency versions.

**Expected result**:

The above command should look for the latest possible version of `podman-compose` where all dependencies work with Python 3.6.8.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#backtracking, https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#possible-solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not specify a particular package version, I was whondering what might be too restrictive here, so that `pip` was not able to resolve dependencies. I did finally get it to work by changing the platform from `linux_x86_64` to `manylinux1_x86_64`:

```
pip download --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --python-version=3.6.8 podman-compose
```

To install the package on the target system, I copied the downloaded files to it and installed them via:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/pip/files podman-compose
```